# SQL Select Statement return rows where first 3 charcters not equal something

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL select query that will return rows from a table and one of the criteria is that the first 3 letters in one specific column are not equal to 'dis','gone', 'pur' or 'tra'

What I have

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, 
FROM [HOME].[dbo].[TABLE] 
Where col1 = '5669' and col4 <> 'I' 
and   left((col5,3) <> ['dis', 'gon', 'pur', 'ret', 'tra'])
```

Can someone enlighten me please?

Thanks,

TD

Comment: did you try:  left((col5,3) NOT IN ['dis', 'gon', 'pur', 'ret', 'tra'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT IN` Clause instead of `<> operator` which will compare list of values. If you want to compare a single value then you can use `<>` but in your case you need to compare against a list of values so use `NOT IN` clause

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,
FROM   [HOME].[dbo].[TABLE]
WHERE  col1 = '5669'
       AND col4 <> 'I'
       AND LEFT(col5, 3) NOT IN ( 'dis', 'gon', 'pur', 'ret', 'tra' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
FROM [HOME].[dbo].[TABLE]
WHERE col1 = '5669' AND col4 <> 'I' AND LEFT(col5,3) NOT IN ('dis','gon',pur','ret',tra')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with a bunch of NOT LIKEs. It is a bit verbose compared to the other examples shown.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, 
FROM [HOME].[dbo].[TABLE] 
Where 
    col1 = '5669' 
    and col4 <> 'I' 
    and col5 NOT LIKE 'dis%'
    and col5 NOT LIKE 'gon%'
    and col5 NOT LIKE 'pur%'
    and col5 NOT LIKE 'ret%'
    and col5 NOT LIKE 'tra%'
```